# Storing the username of user who submitted form using foreignkey?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm building an inventory system using django as a framework. I have a modelform that a logged in user will submit to place an order. all of the fields I want to be filled work with the exception of the 'store' field, which corresponds to the individual who's placing the order. I dont want the user to submit the username which is why it's been excluded in the form, I'd like to override it with 'commit=false' and add it automatically. Fairly new to django so I'm unsure whether this is a problem.

So far I've added a foreignkey from the 'store' field to the user table. However when the form is submitted the 'store' field remains null. I'd like the actual username from users to be placed in this field.

models.py

```
class Sysco(models.Model):
    milk = models.IntegerField(null = True)
    store = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True,)
    oder_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null = True,)

    def __str__(self):
        managed = True
        db_table = 'sysco'
```

form.py

```
class syscoform(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Sysco
        exclude = ('store', 'order_date')
```

views.py

```
class SyscoOrder(TemplateView):
        template_name= "SyscoOrder.html"

        def get(self, request):
                form = syscoform(request.POST,)
                context = {
                        'form'         : form,
                }
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)

        def post(self, request):
                form = syscoform(request.POST,)
                if form.is_valid():
                        form.save(commit=False)
                        form.store = request.user.username
                        form.save()
                        return redirect('Order')

                context ={

                        'form' : form,
                }
                return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Use this `form.store = request.user` and `form.store.username` will be the same as `request.user.username`.

Comment: unfortunately a null value is still inserted.

Answer (score 0):

`form.store` needs a User but you're giving a username.

Change `form.store=request.user.username` to `form.store=request.user`

You will then be able to get the username.

```
sysco = Sysco.objects.get(id=some_id)
username = sysco.store.username
```